# Does Redis support file caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis, memcached

I am working on an app in Ruby on Rails that requires frequent fetching of text files. These files are modified very rarely. Currently the files are fetched from Amazon s3. I would like to create a cache so that I can save on network time. I would prefer in-memory cache rather than writing on filesystem. Is it possible to use Redis or Memcached to store the files? If not what are my other options?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Redis can be used for storing any data, the only limitation is that its protocol supports strings of up to 512MB - if your files are smaller than that, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Thank You. Additionally redis is already in use by sidekiq. Is it safe to use the same server for cache or should I create a new one?

Comment: I'd create a separate dedicated Redis server for that - since Redis is (mostly) single-threaded, it's better to divide and conquer.